# If select query returns null then return lastest entry from db in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have below query which return a result set for certain time interval, like 1 min, 10min, 1hour etc. [below is working e.g. for 10min.]

```
select MemoryUsage, TransactionTime, moduleid
from tbl_trnmemoryusage 
where TransactionTime between (now() - interval 10 minute ) and now() 
order by TransactionTime asc;
```

**Requirement**

If above query does not return anything, that is no data in that time duration, then return last entry based "TransactionTime" column

```
if above_query returns null
then 
select MemoryUsage, TransactionTime, moduleid
from tbl_trnmemoryusage
order by TransactionTime desc limit 1;
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09dbd2/2)**

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for the suggestion now sqlfiddle is added

Comment: Half way there then.

Comment: This isn't a solution but (if I were you and if you are using the query into a code like vb.net) you could send both queries and get results into a dataset. So, if the 1st datatable hasn't rows, you'll take results from the second datatable. Hope this may help. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(t.MemoryUsage, t2.MemoryUsage),
  COALESCE(t.TransactionTime, t2.TransactionTime), 
  COALESCE(t.moduleid, t2.moduleid)
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM tbl_trnmemoryusage 
  ORDER BY TransactionTime DESC
  LIMIT 1
  ) t2
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM tbl_trnmemoryusage
  WHERE TransactionTime BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) and NOW() 
  ORDER BY TransactionTime ASC
) t
ON 1
```

Comment: Your query somehow working at sqlfiddle but no output at my local db for 1min or 10min or 1 hour. NOTE: I have data for last 1 hour.                         by the way there is edit in your query at last OREDER BY -> ORDER BY. pls update.

Comment: I have again retested in the morning and yes the query is working like charm.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tryed this way?

```
select MemoryUsage, TransactionTime, moduleid
from tbl_trnmemoryusage 
where TransactionTime >=
  IF((Select Count(*) from (
    select MemoryUsage, TransactionTime, moduleid
    from tbl_trnmemoryusage 
    where TransactionTime between (now() - interval 10 minute ) and now() 
    ) As Tbl1) > 0, 
   (now() - interval 10 minute),
     (Select Max(TransactionTime)
     from tbl_trnmemoryusage))
order by TransactionTime asc;
```

Comment: Yes this is also working. but not sure performance wise whoes query is better, Alex's or yours. I will run on huge data and see who wins.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNION ALL with a SELECT statement, that will only return a row when no rows are found within the given range.

```sql
select MemoryUsage, TransactionTime, moduleid
from tbl_trnmemoryusage 
where TransactionTime between (now() - interval 10 minute ) and now()
union all
select * from (
    select MemoryUsage, TransactionTime, moduleid
    from tbl_trnmemoryusage
    where not exists (
        select 1 from tbl_trnmemoryusage
        where TransactionTime between (now() - interval 10 minute ) and now()
    )
    order by TransactionTime desc limit 1
) b
order by TransactionTime asc
```

If you don't care about performance or your resulting set is rather small, you can skip the NOT EXISTS condition and let `UIONN DISTINCT` eliminate the duplicate. Note that it would also remove any duplicates that already exist in your DB.

```sql
select MemoryUsage, TransactionTime, moduleid
from tbl_trnmemoryusage 
where TransactionTime between (now() - interval 1 minute ) and now()
union distinct
select * from (
    select MemoryUsage, TransactionTime, moduleid
    from tbl_trnmemoryusage
    order by TransactionTime desc limit 1
) b
order by TransactionTime asc
```